# How to use ifconfig multiple times in one action?

Tags: layout, ifconfig

How to use `ifconfig` two times in one action?

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="example/general/enabled">
    <template>example/catalog/product/view/examples.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Now I want to add another if condition in this action. I have two configuration fields.

If one is set as "yes" and the second is also set as "yes" then my template will be displayed. So how to use two if condition in a layout XML file?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's likely better to allow the `setTemplate` action to execute based on the `example/general/enabled` and **then wrap the contents of the template** in an if statement for the other setting.

**File: example/catalog/product/view/examples.phtml**

```
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('example/general/other_setting')):?>
 // do your other stuff
<?php endif;?>
```

This usually can be tightened up by putting your store config check in a helper or block method that returns the enabled status. You'll see this in Magento as `isEnabled` or `canRender` - something descriptive for those who have to manage this code base after you've gone.

Comment: its only for template but i want this condition in **addTab** than how to do that

Comment: Use a helper at the top of the addTab method

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to use several "ifconfig" statements.

As alternative you can use helper to choose which template to use

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="example/general/enabled">
    <template helper="mymodule/getTemplate"/>
</action>
```

Then you just need to create helper with method

```
public function getTemplate()
{
    //return template path depending on your conditions
    // example/catalog/product/view/examples.phtml
}
```